# Wine has dependency issues

Tags: installation, wine, dependencies, aptitude

Okay, I like to use Aptitude for most of my program installation, due to its exceptional handling of dependencies (it's very diligent about removing unused libraries.)

Unfortunately, it appears not to be able to install Wine.
The log is [here](http://pastebin.com/RsZ8jfra).

Now, I can usually get away with typing `sudo apt-get install wine`, and it will be fine, but the next time I run aptitude (I usually prefer it for programs that have many dependencies,) wine is removed.

Anyway, I didn't manage to figure out what was wrong (I could make out that it has something to do with an unresolvable dependency,) but I was hoping that somebody else could figure it out.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f` : install dependencies. After issuing this command, please comment for update.

Comment: Okay, after `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, I did that, and got [nothing important](http://pastebin.com/mrBsKUfi).

Comment: You have 5 packages not upgraded. You might want to upgrade those ;) (`dist-upgrade`)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Architecture problem with 12.10 Quantal. If is different version just use bottom line and should be fine.

Comment: I'm running 64-bit 12.04 Precise. Do your instructions still apply? If not, please tell me what I need to do.